# cordova-plugin-whitelist request cordova iOS 4.0.0 or above

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

I wanted to add this plugin : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist
but it requires cordova iOS 4.0.0 or above.

I am only able to update to iOS 3.8.0

How can I do ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution :

cordova platform add ios@4.0.x --usegit

Comment: Thanks - I don't know where you found this :) !

Comment: I get 
No compatible version found: cordova-ios@'>=4.0.0 <5.0.0'
Valid install targets:
["3.5.0","3.6.0","3.6.1","3.6.3","3.7.0","3.8.0","3.9.0","3.9.1"]

Comment: now deprecated. use `cordova platform add git-url#custom-branch`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and made a quick fix for my automated build script, just after it created the wrapper I added the following line:

```
sed -i '' "s/\<plugin name=\"cordova-plugin-whitelist\" version=\"1\" \/\>/\<plugin name=\"cordova-plugin-whitelist\" version=\"1.0.0\" \/\>/g" config.xml
```

So this means, change the version="1" into version="1.0.0" and the Problems are solved. Since 4.0.x isn't released yet I'd not recommend to use it.